# ajax_command_append in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to display a list of items by ajax on a link click. My link html is

```
<a class="get-list use-ajax ajax-processed" href="get-my-list">My List</a>
```

I can do this in Drupal 7 by:

```
return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      ajax_command_append('#my-wrapper', theme('item_list', array('items' => $my_list, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('my-list'))))),
    ),
  );
```

How to return an ajax callback like this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the drupal 8 Ajax API (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8)

You can define your own callback function or if you have a link you can go to the method of the controller. Here you will have to define an AjaxResponse and put commands in the response.

Here's an example from my project.

The link buildup

```
$build['ajax-link'] = [
        '#title' => '',
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#id' => 'ajax-link',
        '#url' => $url,
        '#ajax' => [
          'event' => 'click',
          'progress' => [
            'type' => 'none',
          ],
        ],
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'fa fa-heart-o fa-2x ' . $activeClass,
          ],
          'title' => 'Ajax heart',
        ],
      ];
```

The controller method it calls

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#ajax-link', $this->subscribeElementGenerator->generateSubscribeElement($event)));
return $response;
```

The ReplaceCommand just re-generates the link to update it.